# How do I follow the flow of a function that calls itself?

Tags: c++, math, recursion

Well, this is another question taken from this practice exam that was given to me that I just don't know what to do with.

```
int fun5 (int c, int d) {
    if (c <= d) {
        return c;
    } else {
        return fun5(c-d, d) * c;
    }
}
```

When you run the code with value of fun5(9,3), you're supposed to get 162, but I have not idea how to get there. Obviously the first if statement is false, so you go to the else, but then you have to go back to fun5 with those new values, but then the if statement fails again, so you go to the else again, but you just came from there. I'm just a very confused person right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recursion

The first time c=9 and d=3 so you do the else statement: (below with the numbers substituted)

```
return fun5(9-3, 3) * 9;
```

Then you do the next go with c=6 and d=3 so you do the else again

```
return fun5(6-3, 3) * 6;
```

Then you do the next one with c=3 and d=3 so you do the if

```
return 3;
```

Follow it up the stack you get

```
return 3;
return 3 * 6;
return 18 * 9;
```

Final return is 18 * 9 or 162.

Comment: Ohh, you follow it back up. I didn't know that. I guess I'll have to read up a bit on recursion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Let's trace through this and see what happens!

Calling `fun5(9, 3)` will then return the value of

```
  fun5(9, 3)
= fun5(9 - 3, 3) * 3
= fun5(6, 3) * 9
```

Well, we have that

```
  fun5(6, 3)
= fun5(3, 3) * 6
```

Then

```
  fun5(3, 3) = 3
```

So this means that

```
  fun5(6, 3)
= fun5(3, 3) * 6
= 3 * 6
= 18
```

So this means that

```
  fun5(9, 3)
= fun5(6, 3) * 9
= 18 * 9
= 162
```

Which is where your answer comes from.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Along with Twain's answer, this does help. Thanks!